# Angular 4 Update list in Select-Option

Tags: angular, typescript

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="yearSelected" id="year" (click)="filterYear()">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Year</option>
    <option *ngFor="let y of yearsUnique" [value]="y">{{y}}</option>
</select>
<select [(ngModel)]="facultySelected" id="faculty" (click)="filterFaculty()"> 
    <option value="" disabled selected>Faculty</option>
    <option *ngFor="let f of facultiesUnique" [value]="f">{{f}}</option>
</select>
```

After user selects a year, in my TypeScript class I update **facultiesUnique** list with faculties from the same year (in the initial load it loads all faculties):

```js
filterYear() {
    setTimeout(() => {        
        console.log("this.yearSelected " + this.yearSelected);        
        this.filterList = this.courseList.filter((course: CourseModel) =>
            (course.Year.toString().indexOf(this.yearSelected.toString()) !== -1));
        this.facultiesUnique = this.courseList.filter((course: CourseModel) =>
            (course.Year.toString().indexOf(this.yearSelected.toString()) !== -1));
        this.facultiesUnique = this.courseList.map(data => data.Faculty);      
    }, 500);
}
```

However, it is not updating the dropdown with the relevant list.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `(change)="filterYear($event.target.value)"` instead of  `(click)="filterYear()"`.

I have create a demo on **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4-update-list-in-select-option?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

> component.html

```
<select [(ngModel)]="yearSelected" (change)="filterYear($event.target.value)">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Year</option>
    <option *ngFor="let y of yearsUnique" [value]="y">{{y}}</option>
</select>
<select [(ngModel)]="facultySelected"  (change)="filterFaculty($event.target.value)">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Faculty</option>
    <option *ngFor="let f of facultiesUnique" [value]="f.name">{{f.name}}</option>
</select>
```

> component.ts

```
get facultiesUnique() {
    return this.dummyData.filter(items => {
      return items.year == this.yearSelected
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
(ngModelChange)="filterFaculty()"
```

or

```
(change)="filterFaculty()"
```

In the filterFaculty() function you can then get the selected value, it is stored in:

```
this.facultySelected
```

Comment: (click) do triggers, and acts the same as ngModelChange & change.
The problem is not getting the updated facultySelected, but to get the updates list - facultiesUnique

Comment: (click) will also trigger when you just click on the element. It's better to trigger when change occurs.